# Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: angularjs, apache, cors

I have been developing an Angular JS application that talks to PHP/Apache web service.

So far it has been working fine for POST and GET requests, but for PUT I have the following error

`Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

I have tested the API with Postman and it works just fine

Any idea to solve my issue? Thanks

Note that the API server, Apache has the following config already

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Options All
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
```

And Chrome has this response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2016 02:52:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Allow: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,DELETE
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IldvM3Z5eUpKcUI5Q0RXam5UN283TEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV3FnTVpUcFliWjZvczFrM2VuYXpBamI5NmIwR24rdThPWGRuMUZjbjd5K0I2N3F1REp4ZFJVc3U3QnhCZmxmZ0ZONDU4SEVtWm42SUVEWmJhRmF6M1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImMzOTVlNDZhZmNjYWNlM2I1N2FjYjQ4N2FhZDc5ZWY2MWJhYTdiNDBlMWExMGJkYzczYzE1MTczMzAyYzVkMjEifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 15-Feb-2016 04:52:56 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,   Accept
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: can you include all of the headers for the request and response in addition to your server config?

Comment: Apologies, this matter has been since solved for a while now. It's actually rather stupid mistake. If I'm not wrong it's because the API side there was a typo on of the parameters but somehow Chrome just posted that error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apologies, this matter has been since solved for a while now. It's actually rather stupid mistake. If I'm not wrong it's because the API side there was a typo on of the parameters

The pre flight error message on Chrome was arguably misleading

Check your variables if you have similar error like me

Comment: In my situation it is same, i had an TypeError in code so server is breaking also not properly handled that error. In this case chrome error message is misleading..